# Getting Exception authenticating MongoCredential in Mongo Explorer IntelliJ plugin

Tags: mongodb, docker, intellij-idea

Today I have a problem with plugin Mongo Explorer for MongoDB in IntelliJ. Namely, I want to connect with my docker image via Mongo Explorer plugin. Problem is that while connect attempt I am receiving an error like:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=PLAIN, userName='mongoadmin', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}
```

I created a container and run it like:

```
docker run -p 27017-27019:27017-27019 
--name mongo -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongoadmin 
-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret 
-e MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=interviewTest -d mongo
```

with terminal usage and the container is running. 
When I am trying to run my Spring Boot application with application.properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.username=mongoadmin
spring.data.mongodb.password=secret
```

application is starting fine so I am assuming that there is no problem with connection pool to my MongoDB database with Spring Boot application and credentials are correct. The problem occurs when I am trying to establish a connection with the Mongo Explorer plugin added to IntelliJ.

My properties in Mongo Explorer look like:

[image: general]

[image: authentication]

I am not even sure if I suppose to configure something more because this is my first step with DB connector for the nonrelational database in IntelliJ.
I will be grateful for suggestion on how to rid of an error and establish a connection with MongoDB with Mongo Explorer plugin.

Comment: Enable ssl, use "admin" auth database, select SCRAM-SHA-1 auth mechanism

Comment: @AlexBlex
Thanks for a response. The connector was trying to establish a connection but after 30 sec I am receiving Connection Test Failed like
`com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake}, caused by {java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly}}]`

Comment: @AlexBlex I unmarked SSL option and I established a connection. In your opinion SSL is required?

Comment: sorry my bad, checked the registry, indeed ssl is not enabled by default

Comment: @AlexBlex despite it everything works. I established a connection.